# How to compute sum of first k binomial coefficients in O(n) without overflow?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, combinatorics

I am trying to calculate this in `O(N)` without overflow (using C++)

[image]

To clarify, `n`, `r` are given beforehand, and I am trying to find the answer for one instance of `(n,r)` pair in `O(N)`

Here's my trial:

1. Use `O(N)` calculate `ans = n!/(r!(n-r)!2^n)`
2. Let `c = ans`, use `O(N)` to modify `c`: `c /= (n-p); c*=(p+1)` for `p = r-1 to 0`. Add `c` into `ans` for each step

Basically I use `O(N)` to calculate the last term first, then use something like a sliding window to find the second last term, then the next one...until the first term. Sum them up in the process.

While it seems to be correct, the actual run time is still slower than I expected. So I wonder is there any special known tricks on this formula which can boost the performance? If no then is there any way to cut down the constant factor maybe? (based on the following snippet)

Another big problem is I was facing a dilemma: which is I cannot compute `2^(-n)` nor `nCr` alone for big `n`, or it will go underflow / overflow. That's why I tried to compute `2^(-n) * The last term in the summation` and **hope for** the effect will cancel each other so that I won't get underflow / overflow in the whole process. Is there any method to 100% ensure that I won't get underflow / overflow?

*(If possible, I would like to avoid using big integer library)*

```cs
// c++ code snippet to demonstrate the idea 

double ans = 1;
for(int p=n; p>=1; p--){
  ans *= p;
  ans /= 2;
  if(p <= r) ans /= p;
  if(p <= n-r) ans /= p;
}
// now ans = n!/(r!(n-r)!2^n)
// use O(N) more time to find the ultimate ans: summation (n!/(r!(n-r)!2^n)) for r >= 0
double c = ans;
for(int p = r-1; p >= 0; p--){
  c /= (n-p);
  c *= (p+1);
  // Each new c is the next term:  n!/((r-1)!(n-r+1)!2^n)
  ans += c;
}
```

Comment: Wait... that sum doesn't say what the summation variable is. If `n` and `r` are both constants, and the expression inside the sum is `n choose r`, it seems like you're just summing a constant.

Comment: @user2357112 sum (nC0, nC1..nCr), the image is wrong here, I will edit it

Comment: Does your use of `double` imply that you are happy with an approximation?

Comment: @rici yes If the approximation has a precision at least of 10^-8...

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/17202/sum-of-the-first-k-binomial-coefficients-for-fixed-n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate and store log(m!) for each m from 0 to n.

Calculate log(1/2**n).

Now p-th term of the sum is exp(log(n!)-log(p!)-log((n-p)!)+log(1/2**n)).  Add these terms together.

Comment: Sounds like a good method, will give it a try (will use base 2 though for easier implementation)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you start the summation in the first loop? If the first loop would compute the binomial coefficients correctly, you can sum them up and also compute the denominator. At the moment you only compute `ans=2^(-n)`, as the other operations cancel each other.

The sum written out is

```
1/2^n*(1+n+n*(n-1)/2+n*(n-1)*(n-2)/(2*3)+...)
```

Th quotient between two binomials is

```
nC[k+1]/nC[k] = (n-k) / (k+1)
```

Note also that the partial sums with upper index `r` and `n-r-1` have the sum `1` by the binomial theorem.

Comment: If I do not get you wrong, you are saying initialize `ans` to 2^(-n), then use one single loop to do the summation, right?  If that's the case, I am doing this because I'm afraid when n is too large,  2^(-n) would be underflow , so I want to calculate it together with the largest term `nCr` to "hope for" it would not go underflow nor overflow

Comment: Yes, then you will have to compute the greatest term correctly. Or use for larger `n` an approximation formula for the partial binomial sum, see Bernoulli-distribution and the asymptotic approximations for the density and cumulative density function.

Comment: +1 for the equation. problem is that the iteration step on 64 bit `double` will overflow really soon `(n=54,r=27)`  all sums for `n` above this are bad as the iteration step will not fit into double precision anymore and will be truncated ... this lead to significant error. for example for `n=100,r=50` is `double sum=684270969637826229800000000000/2^90` and `bigint sum=680189586700239570843455122823/(2^90)` so only first 2 digits are correct.